# Ajax return full html page

Tags: jquery, ajax, response

im trying get a JSON data from the server via an AJAX call. The call works fine, but 
the success handler not get the correct JSON data generated by the server, instead, get all HTML content of the current page.

My PHP Code (`$_POST['idFoto']` exists):

```
header('Content-type: application/json');

$fotos = FotoQuery::Create()->findByIdfoto($_POST['idFoto']);
if($fotos->count() != 1){
    die("{success: false, msg: 'Error interno, foto no encontrada un&iacute;vocamente.'}");
}
$foto = $fotos->getFirst();
$response = Array('success'=>true,'title'=>$foto->getTitulo(),'nombre'=>$foto->getNombre(),
        'desc'=>$foto->getDescripcion(),'date'=>$foto->getFecha());
echo json_encode($response);
```

My Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: document.domain +"/private/ajaxRequests/fotoRequestHandler.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {idFoto: picId},
    success: function(data,status,request) {
       console.log(data);
       console.log(status);
       console.log(request);
    }
});
```

The status call is "200 OK". Any ideas why this not work appropriately ?

**UPDATE:** When execute the scrip via URL (with a idFoto assigned manually) the `json_encode` works fine:

> {"success":true,"title":"Demo
>   1","nombre":"01.jpg","desc":"Descripci\u00f3n foto demo
>   1.","date":"07/24/13"}

But, i put `die(json_encode($response))` at the end of script, Ajax Call continues reciving full HTML.

**NOTE:** Im use Smarty and friendly URLS, this have an impact on the problem ?.

Comment: Add Datatype in ajax call: dataType (xml or json or script or html)

Comment: @Ani thanks for reply, im forget write this in the thread. When i put `dataType: 'json'` the console.log not executes and the response are still html (check this vis Chrome Dev Tools).

Comment: try `die(json_encode($response));`

Comment: @dfsq thanks, i update the thread, with your suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem, change the url property of the Ajax by `"/private/ajaxRequests/fotoRequestHandler.php"`. And works fine !.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. First clean buffer then print the json. At the end exit!

```
ob_clean();
echo json_encode($response);
die();
```